# Qt: Scale polygons but not children

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt. I am representing events from my application as polygons in my scene, using a custom class that inherits `QGraphicsPolygomItem`. The polygon dimensions are `(event duration, fixed height)`, using 1s : 1px. Event duration can be as low as 1E-6, so I simply scale my view so that the smaller polygon is scaled up to `MIN_POLY_WIDTH` (10px):

`view->scale(qreal(MIN_POLY_WIDTH/min_event_duration), qreal(1.0));`

[image]

So far so good. However, I have a `QGraphicsTextItem` child for each polygon, which get stretched by the scale operation to a point they get way outside the polygon boundaries:

[image]

The text item is created as follows:

```
void EventPolygon::setId(QString id) {                                     
  if (!this->id) {
    this->id = new QGraphicsTextItem(id, this);
  } else {
    this->id->setPlainText(id);
  }
  this->id->setPos(0, this->polygon().boundingRect().height() / 2 - this->id->boundingRect().height() / 2);
}
```

That function is usually called by `EventPolygon` constructor. I though that was the issue, since `scale` is done after all items are added to the scene, so it would affect the text items. So I tried calling `setId` *after* the scale operation, by iterating over all items in the scene. That way I though only the polygons would be stretched. That was not the case, and the text remained stretched.

I also tried using the following instead of `scale`:

```
QTransform t = QTransform();                                                  
t.scale(qreal(MIN_POLY_WIDTH/min_event_duration), qreal(1.0));                           
view->setTransform(t, false);
```

I thought "false" would avoid the transformation being applied to the polygons children, however it seems that is not the case. Is there any way I can scale the polygons to 10px width min and have a readable text inside them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QGraphicsScene` forms a scenegraph hierarchy based upon the parent-child relationships, transformations are inherited down this hierarchy - there is no way round this (see the Transformations section [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#details)).

So to fix your issue, you will need to make the child `QGraphicsTextItem` invert the scaling transformation of the parent multiplied by the scaling of your view.

In fact I really recommend that you **never** set view transformations that are not for simulating a camera operation (pan, zoom, etc.) for this reason.  I would simply allow for the seconds per pixel ratio to vary and allow the child items to be able to query this from the view - in other words have the progress items take care of their own size on screen.

> That was not the case, and the text remained stretched.

Changing the transformation stack will cause a redraw, that's why it doesn't matter *when* you set the scale.

> I thought "false" would avoid the transformation being applied to the
>   polygons children

No, the `combine` argument when false just overrides the existing transformation matrix with the one you are providing.

Comment: I see, I'll change the ratio for now and read more about the scene organization. Thanks.